# Angular observable object mapping issue

Tags: angular

I am consuming an Observable and having issues getting it to map correctly to my model class. I fixed casing issues, per suggestions here, but changing my model to Camel casing didn't help entirely. Is data being bound to the httpresponse instead of my object?

My model class:

```
export class Lease implements ILease {
    public id: string;
    public emailAddress: string;
    public make: string;
    public carModel: string;
    public year: number;
...
}
```

My component.ts:

```
  this.sub = this.leaseSvc.GetLease(this.id).subscribe(
    (data: Lease) => { 
        console.log(this.lease);
        console.log(this.lease.make); // undefined
        console.log(this.lease.Value.make); // works but is wrong
    }...
```

My console output:

{ContentType: null, SerializerSettings: null, StatusCode: null, Value: {…}}ContentType: nullSerializerSettings: nullStatusCode: nullValue: carModel: "Sorento"currentMileage: 355emailAddress: "aaa@aaa.com"firstName: "Bill"id: "5be8925ea21e8b3ef0ac08e9"lastName: "Smith"leaseLength: 60leaseStartDate: "2018-11-01T04:00:00Z"leaseStartMileage: 10make: "Kia"mileSets: []mileageOverageCharge: 0.2password: ""passwordHash: "$2b$10$QZbcf/sWOmBVjDlZ.LvIwOuGb6pq2EaIzZbuM4EhGyUYlFAC.7YlK"trackingInfo: {leaseEndDate: "2023-11-01T04:00:00Z", totalMileageAlloted: 50000, mileageUsed: 345, percentageMileageUsed: 0.69, dailyAllotedMileage: 27.397260273972602, …}year: "2018"yearlyMileageAllotment: 10000zipCode: "30303"**proto**: Object__proto__: Object

lease-stats.component.ts:41 undefined

lease-stats.component.ts:42 Kia

My service.ts code:

```
GetLease(id: string): Observable<Lease> {
  return this.http.get<Lease>(this.serviceUrl + id, this.secureHttpOptions);
}
```

Comment: It should be `this.lease.make`, use `make` not `Make`

Comment: better close this question

Comment: this.lease.make doesn't work because the model has "Make".  I changed the model to "make" and this.lease.make still didn't work any differently.

Comment: @RJA Can you change to log to `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.lease);` and let us know what it says? Also, can you please add the code for `this.leaseSvc.GetLease`

Comment: It's simple: the JSON you receive from the server doesn't match the attributes declared in your class. And this class should be an interface anyway: Angular will never create an instance of your class. It parses the JSON to a POJO and returns that POJO, that's all. So, create an interface which attributes that actually match the names and types of the JSON that the server sends.

Comment: Add your service method too

Comment: I changed all of the model elements to camel cased (again) which makes 
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.lease));
show valid results, but the object isn't still binding correctly.  this.lease.make is still undefined.  Would a bad data element type cause the entire object mapping to fail?  I have a couple elements that are timespan types from C# that could be the problem, if that is the case.

Comment: @JBNizet Can you explain how having an interface would help if the element names are the same in either case?

Comment: An interface defines the shape of an object. So it's perfectly suited here, since the goal is to describe how the POJO deserialized from JSON looks like. Using a class is lying to yourself, since it defines a concrete type, which will never be the type of the POJO deserialized from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the .Net Core RESTful service this Angular app was calling.  It was returning a JsonResult which had the expected object under a "Value" element.  The original Pascal casing of the class in Angular was probably also an issue originally.